# Replace Java Regex Capture Groups with Parts of Themselves

Tags: java, regex, replaceall, capture-group

What is the best way in Java for doing the following replacement on Strings:

I have text that looks similar to this:

```
one two [[**my_word** other words]] three four [[**my_other_word** other words]] five six
```

and I want the following text

```
one two **my_word** three four **my_other_word** five six
```

I tried using regex capture groups but how can I replace one capture group with another one?

Comment: Can you show what you tried and where you got stuck?

Comment: each group have a number $1, $2, $3 ... Then u can use it. $1 = group 1 captured, example $1 = potato => "hi $1" (hi potato).

Comment: I got stuck when I tried using the Java Pattern and Matcher API.

Comment: I added an example of how to use the Pattern and Matcher objects if you are interested in seeing how it could be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm

and do something like

```
a.replaceAll("\\[\\[(\\w+)[^\\[]+\\]\\]", "$1");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a.replaceAll("\\[\\[(\\*\\*\\w+\\*\\*)(?:\\s\\w+\\s?)+\\]\\]", "$1");
```

Comment: The single backslashes you are using are not valid as regex escape characters in java. They need to be double backslashes.

Comment: Hey I just wanted to ping you on your last C++ question.  You had an off by on error.  `std::vector<std::string> base(values->begin() + 1, values->begin() + 4);` only gives you the first 3 elements.  You need to change the 4 to a 5 to get the first 4 elements.

Comment: @NathanOliver ah, I knew it would be a stupid mistake. Didn't know if it was inclusive or exclusive ending bounds. Thanks!

Comment: @m_callens No problem.  Generally then end is never included in the range copied.

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your needs are, you could either use a oneliner like

```
a.replaceAll("\\[\\[(\\*\\*\\w+\\*\\*).*?\\]\\]", "$1");
```

Or the more complicated version where you can control what to replace each match with.

```
String inputString = "one two [[**my_word** other words]] three four [[**my_other_word** other words]] five six";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[(\\*\\*\\w+\\*\\*).*?\\]\\]", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
StringBuffer outputBuffer = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) {
    String match = matcher.group(1);        
    matcher.appendReplacement(outputBuffer, match);
}
matcher.appendTail(outputBuffer);

String output = outputBuffer.toString();
```